# Header in css not as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm new in CSS/HTML and I can't make the design that I want.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
    <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Type...">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url('../assets/images/logo.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.search-bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Photo (I would like the logo to be centered, next to the search bar):
[image: Desired design]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` and `justify-content: center` in your `.header` div to center the elements in the center; Add a `margin-right` to the logo to give a space between the logo and search bar

```css
.header {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/80') no-repeat;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
    <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Type...">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to web dev too, but this should work:

```
.header{
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your desired output. One of the ways using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). You can also have a look at [FLEX: A simple visual cheatsheet for flexbox](https://flexbox.malven.co/).

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

Click on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/yLxYZEb) to see the full code.

Besides, you can also have a look at the link below to see the issue & solution visually: [StackOverFlow QA - Header in css not as expected](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/OBbLPGnNxwe)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Hope it helps someone!